# Using Google HTTP Client in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Android development and I have come across an open source library from Google known as ["Google HTTP Client for Java"](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) that I would like to use within my project to do HTTP Post Requests.

I am not sure how to import this library so that I can use it properly with Android Studio. In the docs it talks about Maven/Gradle which I do not have very much knowledge in, I plan to look more into them at a later time. I am developing the project for Android 4.3+ (API 18).

Can anyone please let me know how to import this properly with Android Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download the JAR files from this link: [Jar Files](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2)

and take a look here [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library/#answer-18321935)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I downloaded the .ZIP file already but there are many .jar files. Do I import them all?

Comment: @Teddy13 see here under `Android` https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup